# maven-clean-plugin or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I'm trying to install `neo4j` on an offline Ubuntu machine. Therefore I tried to build it from the source using :

```
mvn clean install -o
```

But I got following error :

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 has not been 
downloaded from it before.
```

So I downloaded the corresponding jar file manually from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/ on another machine and then transferred it on the Ubuntu one. But now it's unclear what I have to do with that file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven needs Internet access or a Nexus/Artifactory with Internet access (many companies run their own Nexus/Artifactory which mirrors MavenCentral).

While it is theoretically possible to download the relevant jars and install them one by one in the local repository ( `install:install-file`), you will probably spend days installing dozens of artifacts (maybe hundreds).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! Just to know (and if it ever happens to be my only way out...), what would be the steps to follow in order to install those artifacts manually ?

Comment: Use the `install-file` goal to upload a file to the local repository (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html)